# No ringback for outgoing calls sip

Tags: android, sip

I'm developing a SIP client app using Android 2.3+ API, I can make a outgoing call and receive a incoming call successfully by using SipDemo sample codes. but I can't hear any thing before peer answers the call.

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. register to sip provider (mSipManager.open())
2. place a call (mSipManager.makeAudioCall)
3. silence (onRingBack method trigger in SipAudioCallListener)
4. other side answer (onCallEstablished method trigger in SipAudioCallListener)
5. both sides hear each other with good quality

I expect for ring-back tone, in step: 3 instead silence.
Can i do something in onRingBack for hear sip ring-back tone instead of silence.

Comment: any solution found ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your onReceive()

```
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
                            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Thats supposed to start the ringtone. Don't for get to put mediaPlayer.stop(); somewhere in your code. onCallEstablished is where i put mine

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - this does start playing a ringtone, but it plays out loud. How do I make it only play softly like in the ear of the caller not on the speaker.